# Only rebase a merge commit

Tags: git, rebase, atlassian-sourcetree

I am working with git and sourcetree. I just had a problem I didn't know how to gracefully handle:
I wanted to merge a feature branch into a develop branch, it created the commit immediatly because there was no difs, I wanted to make sure the project compile and start anyway before pushing my commit to the server, but in the meantime, someone else pushed a commit into develop. Once I finished to check, I clicked "receive" then "rebase".
I expected my merge commit alone to come ahead, but all the commit of my branch where rebased instead. I had to discard everything and start over.

How should I do to only rebase a merge commit in this situation ?

edit: drawing to clarify (black are my commit, red is someone else's that arrived before I push, the blue is what I want to achieve (only rebase the merge commit).
[image]

here is what I get (I loose the merge commit and the whole branch get rebased):

[image]

Comment: The verbiage you're using in this context is a wee bit confusing.  Are you saying that you had a fast-forward merge on a branch and you want to revert that?

Comment: I edited my first post with colored balls

Comment: So you're looking to do a squash-merge, then?  Take the sum of the contents of all three of your commits and merge it into one single commit?

Comment: it's the opposite, I already did what I wanted by just starting over, I only wanted to "push after the red commit", without touching my history.

Comment: 1. Hard reset to last black. 2. Rebase (pull rebase)